# Retrieve and use entire MYSQL Table in Swift

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, swift

I've looked around the internet but have yet to come across a solution to what it seems like should be a common practice.

I am trying to write a method in Swift which, using a PHP backend, retrieves all the data from a specific MYSQL table in my database.

In other sections of the app (user login etc) I have already got a similar system working, but this only needs to return a few variables for one specific user, so I can just return these in JSON data as individual variables and store them in the NSUserDictionary for use throughout the app, easy!

However now I have another table with information about different 'shops' with each row storing various details (location, name etc). I want to be able to plot these with their names onto a MKMapView and therefore I need to retrieve the entire table and then iterate through each row (shop) within swift. (Well that's the only way I can think of accomplishing this).

My issue is I can only figure out how to return '1D' JSON data in PHP (e.g. the location / name etc for a specific shop), not for an entire array of shops?

This is the code I'm using in swift to retrieve the 1D data for a user:

```
        var post:NSString = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.agentsweep.co.uk/scripts/agentsweep_user_login.php")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

And this is the backend PHP part which returns it:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, fullname, mobile, mobilepref, address, autofill FROM users WHERE email = '$email';")) {
                $userData = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $result->close();
            }  

            $fullnameResult = $userData["fullname"];
            $idResult = $userData["id"];
            $mobileResult = $userData["mobile"];
            $mobilePrefResult = $userData["mobilepref"];
            $addressResult = $userData["address"];
            $autofillResult = $userData["autofill"];
            /* close connection */
            $mysqli->close();

            if ($id) {

                error_log("User $email: password match.");


                /* Reply Data:*/
                /*echo '{"success":1,"id":'. $idResult .',"fullname":'. $fullname .',"mobile":'. $mobileResult .',"mobilepref":'. $mobilePrefResult .',"address":'. $addressResult .'}';
            */
                echo '{"success":1,"idref":"'. $idResult .'","fullname":"'. $fullnameResult .'","mobile":"'. $mobileResult .'","mobilepref":"'. $mobilePrefResult .'","address":"'. $addressResult .'","autofill":"'. $autofillResult .'"}';
```

Can someone give me a clear explanation of how to process an entire table rather than just one row? Thank you very much, will up-vote all useful answers and select the best one asap! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:
  it is considered **bad** thing to send too much data to the client, imagine that you'll have 70,000 results for that sql, will you really gonna send the user 15MB of data? I dont think so :). you should learn how to use pagination using *skip* and *limit*

answer:

well, first let's improve your PHP code

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, fullname, mobile, mobilepref, address, autofill FROM users WHERE email = '$email';")) {

    $userData = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $userData[] = $row;
    }

    //no need to write a json by your self, php does it alone
    echo json_encode($userData);

    //add all mysqli->close()

}
```

on swift:

```
//you did this:
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

and just iterate on it

```
for (k,v) in jsonData {
   println("jsonData[\(k)] = \(v)") //a row from your SQL result
}
```